# mypy throws "error: Too many arguments for 'object'" on pre-commit hook run but not on local run

Tags: mypy, python-poetry, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

```py
from typing import Callable, Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def repo(class_: Type[T]) -> Callable:
    def instantiate(*args, **kwargs) -> T:
        return class_(*args, **kwargs)

    return instantiate
```

Code above throws "error: Too many arguments for 'object'" on pre-commit hook run but not on local run (`python poetry run mypy repo.py`).
Neither error message nor difference of behaviour between hook and local run make sense to me.
Any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: show your configuration, show the output, show the command you ran, show the versions of the tools you're using

Comment: Note that Git doesn't do anything special in terms of Python paths during hook runs, so this is probably actually a shell (.bashrc, .profile, etc.) item. You might set up a path for yourself at the command line that you don't set up for other programs, thereby giving yourself a different `mypy` when you run it from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got a version mismatch between your two environments.

the one that is failing is `mypy<=0.910`:

```
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.910
$ mypy t.py
t.py:7: error: Too many arguments for "object"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

the one that's passing is `mypy>0.910`

```
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.971 (compiled: yes)
$ mypy t.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```